# Update property control value using another property control: Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I am trying to achieve a functionality where I want to update the value of a property control using another property control. 
Below is the example, I have a dropdown list property control named AsOfDate which holds the date information. Using the value selected in the dropdown list, I would like to display the related quarter information right next to the dropdown list in the form of dropdown or list box (this field will later be used as a column header for my reports).

**This is the approach I have:**

1. Created a dropdown list property control.
2. Using the value from the dropdown list, created a calculated column with 
   Quarter information.
3. Used the value from the calculated column (step 2) in another property 
   control.

**Problem:**

The value for step 3 is getting calculated properly but is not getting updated unless there is user input. How do I make the value for property control to update based on just selecting the AsofDate (w/o any further user input).

**Calculated Column Code:**

```
case  
when Quarter(DocumentProperty("AsofDate")) IN (1) then 
Concatenate(Quarter(DocumentProperty("AsofDate")),Year(DocumentProperty("AsofDate"))) 
when Quarter(DocumentProperty("AsofDate")) IN (2, 3, 4) then 
Concatenate(Quarter(DocumentProperty("AsofDate")),Year(DocumentProperty("AsofDate")))
end
```

In the attached screenshot, as you can see the quarter information is there when we expand the second dropdown but it is not displaying unless selected by user.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's say your two dropdown controls are linked to a pair of document properties called `A` and `B`. the possible values of `A` are 1-4. the possible values for `B` are based on unique values in the calculated column `[col]`, which is a concatenation of some string and the value of `A`.

when I initially set the value of `A` to 1, `[col]` now will contain values like "Something1", "SomethingElse1", "SomeThirdThing1". the dropdown attached to `B` now contains those three values, and I select "Something1", thereby setting the value of `B` to "Something1".

next, I change the value of `A` to 3. `[col]` updates to contain "Something3", etc. the dropdown attached to `B` now shows "---".

the reason this happens is because the **Document Property** `B` is not updated; it's still set to "Something1", even though the *acceptable values* for its attached **Property Control** are now "Something3" etc.

there is no mechanism within Spotfire to account for this; it requires some scripting.

assuming the example I posed here, add the following script to be executed anytime the value of `A` changes. it will always update the value of `B` to the first result in column `[col]`.

```
# import the DataValueCursor class
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataValueCursor

# set up the data table reference
dt = Document.Data.Tables["Data Table"]
# set up the column reference
col = DataValueCursor.CreateFormatted(dt.Columns["col"])

# move the cursor to the first row of the column
# (GetRows() returns an iterable, and next() advances it to the first result)
dt.GetRows(col).next()

# update the document property
Document.Properties["B"] = col.CurrentValue
```

all that said, while this is an interesting case I wonder what it is you're trying to do and if there isn't a better way. this solution works for the question you posed but I would be curious to know what your end goal is and if there's a more appropriate solution for that problem.

Comment: Niko, the idea behind this approach is to find a dynamic header for my crosstab columns. Based on my first dropdown (which is the date), my goal is to display the quarter/previous quarter and year information for my crosstab header. If I get my second dropdown to change on the fly based on 1st one, I would be able to use that as my cross tab column header.

Comment: @Shane, if all you need is a static header, I would suggest going with a Label control and assigning the value to `B` using ironpython scripting. alternatively, you could create a hierarchy column and set that as your column axis for the cross table. of course if the second dropdown is to provide some filtering function, then maybe this approach will work.

Comment: creating hierarchy is not an option as there is fair amount of logic/filtering in custom expression of cross tab columns. Will go with labels. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you need to add a script that runs when that property control is changed and refreshes the text area that those drop-down boxes are in.

Below is a sample python script that would do this (with a parameter for the page. You could refresh all text areas on all pages if it wont slow down your script too much):

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import Visualization, 
VisualTypeIdentifiers, HtmlTextArea

#Iterate through the page visualisations
for viz in page.Visuals:
        if viz.TypeId == VisualTypeIdentifiers.HtmlTextArea:
            viz.As[HtmlTextArea]().HtmlContent += " ";
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: this code didn't work in the test document I set up. the issue isn't with the HTML content itself being updated. will provide more detail in an answer.